# Convert a callable object to Function while maintaining it's hashCode

Tags: dart

```
void main() {
  Iterable<CallableObject> a = [new CallableObject()];
  test(a); // gives warning
}

class CallableObject
{
  CallableObject call(){return this;}
}

void test(Iterable<Function> test){
  print(test);
}
```

This code throws an error since the `CallableObject` cannot be type casted into a Function. Is there any way to type cast it, while maintaining the hashCode of that CallableObject?

Note: I have solved the error by playing the type-casting, by creating a function that returns a Function and then by returning that strongly typed object.

Something like this...

```
Function converter(CallableObject _)=>_;
```

Comment: You cannot cast it into `Function` until it's a  `Function`. You need to inherit `Function` to cast it into Function. Could you please share the exact requirement?

Comment: I want it to pass it to a function that accepts a `Function` as a parameter

Comment: If your class implements `call()` you can use it as a `Function` without the need of casting.

Comment: I need to pass it as a parameter to another function where it will be called.

Comment: Can you give an example of this which show it does not work?

Comment: @SanjaySharma Also, extending `Function` class is now deprecated.

Comment: DartPad doesn't seem to give error but my Flutter project/plugin does while compiling the code...

Comment: What about running with Dart VM? Can it e.g. be reproduced by compiling to AOT?

Comment: But how would that solve the error?

Comment: I can't help you unless I can reproduce your problem on my own machine. So I am looking into a way to reproduce the problem. But if it only happens on Flutter, then please link to a Flutter project which shows the problem.

Comment: `Iterable<Function> a = notifiers.notify`

Comment: it works on flutter too, I had cases - just implemented `call()` and passed instance of Foo as arg

Comment: I solved the issue....It was probably because the variables were too strongly typed. I have updated my answer with an example code that reproduces that error and a solution.

Comment: `Iterable<Function> a = notifiers.notify` this can be called as `a.foreach((fn) => fn())`

Comment: Yes, I made the getter `notify` return `Iterable<Function>` instead of `Iterable<Notifier>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot control the hash code of the function.

The conversion to `Function` creates a new object, and it's a function object that you have no way to control the `hashCode` of.

The one thing you could potentially do is to use that function's hash code as the hash of the object. Since instance method tear-offs of the same function from the same object are equal, they also have the same hash code, so:

```dart
class CallableObject {
  CallableObject call() {
    return this;
  }
  int get hashCode => this.call.hashCode;
}
```

Then the `hashCode` of the function created by tearing off `call` will equal the `hashCode` of the originall callable object.

That only fixes the hash code, which is rarely the real problem.
It does not fix equality, and you can't do that in both directions.
You can add

```dart
  bool operator==(Object other) => 
    other is CallableObject 
        ? super.== other 
        : other is Function && this.call == other;
```

but it won't help for the other direction.

Comment: Overriding the getter `hashCode` and `operator==` function was a brilliant idea! Thanks for the help.